# Unexpected execution of ngOnInit Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular5

I made request to server in

```
ngOnInit() {

this.service.get(1).subscribe((response) => {
   this.whenDateCurrent = new DateCustomDate();
});
}
```

Also in this component I have method that returns `this.whenDateCurrent`:

```
public getCurrentDate(): string {
    return this.whenDateCurrent.prev.day;
}
```

I call this function from template:

```
<input mdInput readonly class="dateRange" name="dateRange" [value]="getCurrentDate()">
```

Problem is that function `getCurrentDate()` is called before loaded: `this.service.get(1).subscribe((response) => {}`

So, it invokes an error:

> Cannot read property 'prev' of undefined

Comment: Did you try to move this.whenDateCurrent outside of the service call?  What else have you tried?  Is there a reason you are setting the value of your input as the return of a function, rather than a variable which you can set elsewhere?

Comment: I tried, the same result, as I know first should be called ngOnInit, but called `getCurrentDate()`

Comment: Why do you have to use a function for input box value?

Comment: Maybe be put all code in constructor?

Comment: I use function to return current date in input box

Comment: changing ur code like this may work:

public getCurrentDate(): string {
this.service.get(1).subscribe((response) => {
   this.whenDateCurrent = new DateCustomDate();
    return this.whenDateCurrent.prev.day;
});


}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use *ngIf to only load the element once whenDateCurrent exists? That way, the getCurrentDate() method will only be called after whenDateCurrent has data.

Make sure to initialize whenDateCurrent to null, for instance:

```
whenDateCurrent?: Date = null;

constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.get(1).subscribe((response) => {
    this.whenDateCurrent = new DateCustomDate();
  });
}

public getCurrentDate(): string {
    return this.whenDateCurrent.prev.day;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<input *ngIf="whenDateCurrent" mdInput readonly class="dateRange" name="dateRange" [value]="getCurrentDate()">
```

Comment: Make sure that whenDateCurrent starts out as null. I have edited my answer. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Do you know how does it work in Facebook, when page is loading it shows empty gray blocks instead content

Comment: You can show whatever type of element you would like by doing the opposite logic *ngIf="!whenDateCurrent". When data comes back from the service, this element will be removed and the *ngIf="whenDateCurrent" element will be added.

Comment: But is hide element still it is null, I need display this anyway like gray block

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehcejx Here is a very minimal example, after 5 seconds, the value will be changed and you will see the second div.